# Was Yakov separated from Yosef the same length of time he was separated from Yitzak?

Tags: vayishlach, vayigash

I was told that the time Yakov was separated from Yitzak was 22 years, but in Bresheit 31:38 (Yakov speaking) "These twenty years I have been with you..." Were there two more years before he was reunited with his father?
In a related experience the time Yosef was in Mitzraim and separated from his father Yakov was that 22 years?

I realize there are two questions in this description but they are presented in this way to see if there is a correlation between the separation period that Yakov had with Yitzak and then again between Yakov and Yosef.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Midrash you heard referred to is on Megillah 17a and it does correlate the two periods. The two missing years from Yaakov's time to get to 22 are from his travel back and are listed as 18 months in Sukkot (Gen 33:17) and 6 months in Beit-El (35:6). The Yosef calculation is based on Yosef being kidnapped at age 17 (37:2), standing before Paroh at 30 (41:46), plus 7 years of plenty and 2 years of famine yielding 22 years. See there for the details.